# Customize Mysql DB fetch in Office Excel

Tags: mysql, excel, ms-office

I am able to fetch a sql query from excel using the odbc connection:

But the issue is that, instead of just give a stack query setup and make user can only click the refresh button, I wish I could have some fields before the result, which user can enter some custom variables(e.g date from, date to)

so when they click refresh button,  excel will take the variables of what user inputted into the pre-defined sql query and fetch the result from my sql server.

Answer (score 0):

To do this sort of thing you need to run one query to fetch the initial values of your custom variables from the DBMS.  For example, if you want to let the user change the date range, do this.

1. Use a query fetch the minimum and maximum date from the date column of your table.

   ```
   SELECT MIN(date) mindate, MAX(date) maxdate
     FROM table
   ```
2. Display those dates and let the user edit them on your form.
3. Put the results of those edited items into your second query, and retrieve the data the user asked for.

   ```
   SELECT (whatever) 
     FROM table
    WHERE date BETWEEN user-min-date AND user-max-date
   ```

The same kind of steps will work to populate a dropdown or listbox with a category

```
    SELECT DISTINCT category
      FROM table
     ORDER BY category
```

Then

```
    SELECT (whatever)
      FROM table
     WHERE category = user-selected-category
```

I *think* this addresses your question.  Please clarify if it doesn't.